# Fine-tuning performance vs. executable size optimizations

Tags: optimization, rust, avr, binary-size

I have a Rust program whose executable size I'd like to decrease by 15-20% compared to its `opt-level = 3` size. What makes me hopeful is that compiling with `opt-level = "s"`, i.e. asking Rust to optimize for size, I get a 45% size decrease compared to the performance-optimized version:

| Optimization level | Code size (`.text` + `.data` segments) |
| --- | --- |
| `3` | 27,380 bytes |
| `2` | 23,934 bytes |
| `1` | 27,852 bytes |
| `s` | 15,132 bytes |
| `z` | 15,264 bytes, but miscompiled (must be some LLVM AVR backend bug, wouldn't be the first...) |

However, the runtime performance of the `s`-optimized version doesn't meet my performance requirements (it's a game for a fixed hardware platform, so there's a performance requirement coming from the frame rate).

Before I start putting in "real work" to decrease code size and/or improve performance by writing "better" code, I'd like to explore what the compiler can do for me. [Initially](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75362230/477476) I thought I can just try tuning the `inline-threshold` setting, but based on the comments on that question, there's (a lot) more going on between Rust's `"s"` vs `3` optimization levels.

So my question is, what are the various parameters/axes/degrees of freedom of the Rust compiler than I can fine-tune in the hope of getting acceptable performance and smaller code size?

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd recommend reading https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust - it suggests a few other things you can tweak to reduce binary size.

Comment: @JoeClay unfortunately most of those suggestions either apply by default on AVR, or I am already applying them.

Comment: Separating your application into several crates, then compiling the performance critical ones with `opt-level = 3` and the rest with `opt-level = s` (or some other combination) is an option

Comment: So why Rust in the 1st place? Not because Rust itself is a bad choice, but because: 1) Rust uses LLVM as a backend, and AVR backend in LLVM is full of bugs. Just in a week or so I found ~20 bugs. Plus is that they are fixed in a timely manner (1 month or so), but avr-llvm is so unstable it's just good for some experiments. 2) In GNU-C (like with avr-gcc) you have very fine-grained control (on function level and up) of optimization options, like inlining, cloning, optimization-level, etc. 3) GCC is just getting a Rust fronted, but it might be too unstable for serious projects.

Comment: This is an Document from Atmel for optimizing C code on AVR but most aspects should apply for rust too, like using smaller integer types: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/doc8453.pdf